# Android MediaPlayer loop has gaps even with OGG format

Tags: android, audio

In Android 4.x my audio looping app has 0.2 to 0.5 second gaps in the sound loops.

I'm using MediaPlayer as my sounds can be quite large (2-3mb each in some cases) and it can run multiple instances at the same time.

I have researched this quite a bit and I see there is a bug for Android 4.x... however, I have tried many work arounds and I can't seem to get any of them working.

- Converted all the wavs to OGG using Audacity (quality level 2 to 10, it didn't matter)
- Tried setNextMediaPlayer()
- Tried to use seekTo(0) on stop and repeat
- Tried soundPool which has its own bugs

Here's a sample of the code I'm using:

```
public class SoundPlayer implements OnCompletionListener {
    private MediaPlayer mp = null;

    public void initPlayer() {
        if(mp == null) {
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
        }
    }

    public void prepare(Context context, int resource) {
    initPlayer();
    try{
        mp.reset();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.myapp.app/"+resource);
        mp.setDataSource(context,uri);
        mp.prepare();
        isPrepared = true;
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }


.......... etc (Uses typical MediaPlayer methods such as stop(), start(), setLooping(true)


}
```

I'm not using anything special, so I'm just wondering if anyone knows of a work around for the looping bug on Android.

Comment: Are you the gap is not being caused by a simple lag in loading and the re-creating of your MediaPlayer object?

Comment: Are you using an emulator, I had a problem similar to this on an emulator but when I tried it with an actual device - the lag was gone.

Comment: Using a GS3 device not emulator. It does feel like lag but how would I prevent that?

Comment: Did you find a solution

Answer (score 1):

Okay old Post, but this solution works. This is kind of hack. It'll help somebody if somebody came to this answer.

I am just using three media players. `mp1`, `mp2`, `mp3`. `mp1` gets play, and I set `mp2` to its `setNextMediaPlayer`. when `mp1` ends, I set `mp3` to `mp2's` `setNextMediaPlayer`. when `mp2` ends, I set `mp1` to `mp3's` `setNextMediaPlayer`. Following is the complete code which play pause, stop, set vol. Just create an object `BZMediaPlayer`, start it by providing `uri`, or resource id.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

public class BZMediaPlayer {


    private Context context;
    private Uri uri;
    private int resourceId;

    // which file is getting played
    public static final int URI_PLAYING = 1;
    public static final int RESOURCE_PLAYING = 2;
    private int filePlaying;

    // states of the media player
    public static final int STATE_PLAYING = 1;
    public static final int STATE_PAUSED = 2;
    public static final int STATE_STOP = 3;

    // current state
    private int state = STATE_STOP;

    // current mediaPlayer which is playing
    private int mediaPlayerIndex = -1;

    // 3 media players
    private MediaPlayer mp[] = new MediaPlayer[3];

    // current volume
    private float vol;


    public BZMediaPlayer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * plays the provided uri
     * @param uri
     */
    public void play(Uri uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
        // current playing file
        filePlaying = URI_PLAYING;
        // stop any playing session
        stop();

        // initialize and set listener to three mediaplayers
        for (int i = 0; i < mp.length; i++) {
            mp[i] = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri);
            mp[i].setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);
        }

        // set nextMediaPlayers
        mp[0].setNextMediaPlayer(mp[1]);
        mp[1].setNextMediaPlayer(mp[2]);

        // start the first MediaPlayer
        mp[0].start();
        // set mediaplayer inex
        mediaPlayerIndex = 0;
        // set state
        state = STATE_PLAYING;
    }

    /**
     * play file from resource
     * @param resourceId
     */
    public void play(int resourceId) {
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
        filePlaying = RESOURCE_PLAYING;
        stop();
        for (int i = 0; i < mp.length; i++) {
            mp[i] = MediaPlayer.create(context, resourceId);
            mp[i].setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);
        }

        mp[0].setNextMediaPlayer(mp[1]);
        mp[1].setNextMediaPlayer(mp[2]);

        mp[0].start();
        mediaPlayerIndex = 0;
        state = STATE_PLAYING;
    }

    /**
     * play if the mediaplayer is pause
     */
    public void play() {
        if (state == STATE_PAUSED) {
            mp[mediaPlayerIndex].start();
            Log.d("BZMediaPlayer", "playing");
            state = STATE_PLAYING;
        }
    }

    /**
     * pause current playing session
     */
    public void pause() {
        if (state == STATE_PLAYING) {
            mp[mediaPlayerIndex].pause();
            Log.d("BZMediaPlayer", "pausing");
            state = STATE_PAUSED;
        }
    }

    /**
     * get current state
     * @return
     */
    public int getState() {
        return state;
    }

    /**
     * stop every mediaplayer
     */
    public void stop() {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < mp.length ; i++) {
            if (mp[i] != null) { 
                mp[i].stop();

                if(mp[i].isPlaying()) {
                    mp[i].release();
                }
            }   
        }
        state = STATE_STOP;
    }

    /**
     * set vol for every mediaplayer
     * @param vol
     */
    public void setVol(float vol) {
        this.vol = vol;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < mp.length ; i++) {
            if (mp[i] != null && mp[i].isPlaying()) {
                mp[i].setVolume(vol, vol);
            }   
        }
    }

    /**
     * internal listener which handles looping thing
     */
    private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener completionListener = new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer curmp) {
            int mpEnds = 0;
            int mpPlaying = 0;
            int mpNext = 0;
            if(curmp == mp[0]) {
                mpEnds = 0;
                mpPlaying = 1;
                mpNext = 2;
            }
            else if(curmp == mp[1]) {
                mpEnds = 1;
                mpPlaying = 2;
                mpNext = 0;  // corrected, else index out of range
            }
            else if(curmp == mp[2]) {
                mpEnds = 2;
                mpPlaying = 0; // corrected, else index out of range
                mpNext = 1; // corrected, else index out of range
            }

            // as we have set mp2 mp1's next, so index will be 1
            mediaPlayerIndex = mpPlaying;
            Log.d("BZMediaPlayer", "Media Player " + mpEnds);
            try {
                // mp3 is already playing release it
                if (mp[mpNext] != null) {
                    mp[mpNext].release();
                }
                // if we are playing uri
                if (filePlaying == URI_PLAYING) {
                    mp[mpNext] = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri);
                } else {
                    mp[mpNext] = MediaPlayer.create(context, resourceId);
                }
                // at listener to mp3
                mp[mpNext].setOnCompletionListener(this);
                // set vol
                mp[mpNext].setVolume(vol, vol);
                // set nextMediaPlayer
                mp[mpPlaying].setNextMediaPlayer(mp[mpNext]);
                // set nextMediaPlayer vol
                mp[mpPlaying].setVolume(vol, vol);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Hope it will help somebody

`Edit: clean code`

Comment: Thank you for this solution! However there were 2 bugs, I edited the source code accordingly. Works great now! Thank you again!

Comment: I've implemented this in my game (using libGDX) and it works a treat. I had to copy a LOT of classes from the source code and butcher some stuff, but the principal here works.

Great stuff @moonzai

Comment: @RussWheeler my pleasure buddy :-)

Comment: @moonzai in my case looping is not working.audio plays only once and stops. Can u help me?